# How to pass multiple parameter in blazor GetFromJsonAsync?

Tags: .net-core, blazor

Good Day Guys,

How to pass multiple parameter in blazor GetFromJsonAsync, I get error when using this code.

blazor webassembly

```
data= await http.GetFromJsonAsync<dataobject[]>($"api/Sample/Get/{id}/{date}");
```

.net core api

```
    [HttpGet("Get/{id}/{date}")]
    public ActionResult<List<dataobject>> Get(string id, string date)
    {
        
        
    }
```

Comment: As far as I can see, that seems correct, whats the error you are getting? Share your error or issue in more details

Comment: This is the error I get. Unhandled exception rendering component: The provided ContentType is not supported; the supported types are 'application/json' and the structured syntax suffix 'application/+json'.

Comment: The api works when using POSTMAN, but i can't make it run in blazor webassembly

Comment: I get it now, I'm passing date with format yyyy/MM/dd, just change it to yyyy-MM-dd.

Comment: For an explanation about the error, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/63863447/60761

Comment: @user8551826 - the way to round this up is to post a self-answer or maybe to just delete the question.

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned in the comment of your question you are using date as this format `yyyy/MM/dd` which means the `/` is considered as URL path. So you will need to URL encode your date which will become like this `yyyy%2FMM%2Fdd` which is now safe to send as URL path.

You can use `HttpUtility.UrlEncode` for URL encoding. Details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httputility.urlencode?view=netcore-3.1)